# What is the correct way to define a DecidableType module?

Tags: coq, module

I have this type in Coq:

```
Inductive s_symb : Type :=
| s_symb_expr : nat -> s_symb 
| s_symb_fld : nat -> list string -> s_symb.
```

I want to create a MSetWeakList of s_symb, so I need to prove the type decidable. My usual routine, learnt from some StackOverflow articles, is along these lines:

```
From Coq Require Import MSets.MSetWeakList.
From Coq Require Import Structures.DecidableType.
From Coq Require Import Structures.DecidableTypeEx.

Module SSymb_as_MDT <: MiniDecidableType.
  Definition t := s_symb.

  Theorem eq_dec : forall s1 s2 : s_symb, { s1 = s2 } + { s1 <> s2 }.
  Proof.
    intro s1. induction s1. intro s2. destruct s2.
    - assert ({n = n0} + {n <> n0}) by apply Nat.eq_dec. sauto.
    - sauto.
    - intro s2. destruct s2.
      * assert ({n = n0} + {n <> n0}) by apply Nat.eq_dec. sauto.
      * assert ({n = n0} + {n <> n0}) by apply Nat.eq_dec. assert ({l = l0} + {l <> l0}) by apply ListString_as_MDT.eq_dec. sauto.
  Defined.
End SSymb_as_MDT.

Module SSymb_as_UDT <: UsualDecidableType := Make_UDT(SSymb_as_MDT).
Module SSymb_as_DT <: DecidableType := UDT_to_DT(SSymb_as_UDT).

Module SetSymb := MSetWeakList.Make(SSymb_as_DT).
```

Unfortunately this does not work: the last row is rejected with the error "The field eq_equiv is missing in SSymb_as_DT". So I read more StackOverflow and I learnt that I shall also define eq_equiv, a proof of the fact that the equality is an equivalence. I tried to add it to SSymb_as_MDT this way:

```
Module SSymb_as_MDT <: MiniDecidableType.
  Definition t := s_symb.
  Definition eq := @eq s_symb.

  Theorem eq_dec : forall s1 s2 : s_symb, { s1 = s2 } + { s1 <> s2 }.
  Proof. (* as above *)
  Defined.

  Theorem eq_equiv : Equivalence eq.
  Proof.
    split. congruence. congruence. congruence.
  Defined.
End SSymb_as_MDT.
```

but while Coq is happy with the definitions and the new proof, still the module SSymb_as_DT cannot see it, and I have the same error message. What shall I do for eq_equiv to be visible to SSymb_as_DT? As a second question, why eq_equiv was missing in first place? Shouldn't Make_UDT or UDT_to_DT add it in a somehow standard way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got confused because there are two definitions of `DecidableType` in the Coq standard library, and you happened to use the deprecated one.

You imported `Structures.DecidableType` which is deprecated. [From its documentation](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Structures.DecidableType.html):

> NB: This file is here only for compatibility with earlier version of FSets and FMap. Please use Structures/Equalities.v directly now.

So replace the imports of `DecidableType` and `DecidableTypeEx` with

```
From Coq Require Import Structures.Equalities.
```

The actual `DecidableType` you need is a supertype of `UsualDecidableType`, which you got from `Make_UDT`.

```
Module SSymb_as_UDT <: UsualDecidableType := Make_UDT(SSymb_as_MDT).
Module SetSymb := MSetWeakList.Make(SSymb_as_UDT).
```

Comment: I see. I had imported it precisely because I also use FMaps. I cannot see any nondeprecated implementation of maps in the standard library.

Comment: There is a package https://github.com/coq-community/coq-mmaps